# Переопределение макроса

Tags: c++, макросы

Подскажите, можно ли определить макрос так, чтобы в зависимости от того, использовался он, или нет, он принимал разные значения ?

Пример:

```
#ifndef DISABLE_MANGLING
#   define DISABLE_MANGLING \
        extern "C" {
#else
#   undef  DISABLE_MANGLING
#   define DISABLE_MANGLING \
        }
#endif
```

*Ожидания*: используя макрос первый раз - он раскрывается в `extern "C" {`, второй раз - раскрывается в `}`.

*Реальность*: в обоих случаях раскрывается в `extern "C" {`.

Что подскажите ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вы хотите не получится, т.к. препроцессор не будет выполнять ранее написанный `#ifdef` встречая в тексте  макрос.

Теоретически можно написать что-то такое (я сократил `DISABLE_MANGLING` до `DM`)

```
#ifndef DM
#define DM extern "C" {
#define DME 1
#else
#undef DM
#if DME == 1
#undef DME
#define DME 2
#define DM }
#else
#undef DME
#define DME 1
#define DM extern "C" {
#endif
#endif


DM 1
#if DME == 1
#undef DME
#undef DM
#define DME 2
#define DM }
#else
#undef DME
#undef DM
#define DME 1
#define DM extern "C" {
#endif


DM 2
#if DME == 1
#undef DME
#undef DM
#define DME 2
#define DM }
#else
#undef DME
#undef DM
#define DME 1
#define DM extern "C" {
#endif

DM 3
#if DME == 1
#undef DME
#undef DM
#define DME 2
#define DM }
#else
#undef DME
#undef DM
#define DME 1
#define DM extern "C" {
#endif

DM 4
```

и получить в результате

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc -E dm.c
# 1 "dm.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "dm.c"
# 18 "dm.c"
extern "C" { 1
# 32 "dm.c"
} 2
# 45 "dm.c"
extern "C" { 3
# 58 "dm.c"
} 4
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

но, не думаю, что это хоть как-то может пригодиться на практике.

Также, поскольку текст, получаемый в результате раскрытия макроса, повторно не анализируется препроцессором, такая попытка уменьшить объем кода

```
#define XX \
#if DME == 1 \
#undef DME \
#undef DM \
#define DME 2 \
#define DM } \
#else \
#undef DME \
#undef DM \
#define DME 1 \
#define DM extern "C" { \
#endif

DM 1
XX
```

не сработает.

В принципе (если уж очень хочется) сократить количество текста можно, записав `#ifdef`-ы в отдельный файл

```
// dm.h file
#ifndef DM
#define DM extern "C" {
#define DME 1
#else
#undef DM
#if DME == 1
#undef DME
#define DME 2
#define DM }
#else
#undef DME
#define DME 1
#define DM extern "C" {
#endif
#endif
```

и включая его в "основной код" вот таким образом

```
// dm.c
#include "dm.h"
DM 1

#include "dm.h"
DM 2

#include "dm.h"
DM 3

#include "dm.h"
DM 4
```